# Insertion sort error list index

Tags: python, insertion-sort, insertion

I am trying to create an array of 7 randomly generated numbers and then sorting these numbers from smallest to highest using the insertion sort method. I have looked through several previously answered topics as it is a very common question but each user has very different code to me which makes me wonder where I am going wrong.

```
import random # importing the random module
arrayInsertion = []

for i in range (7): # 7 different numbers
    arrayInsertion.append(random.randint (1,10))

for i in range (1,7):
    while  i > 0 and arrayInsertion [i+1] > arrayInsertion [i]:
        arrayInsertion [i] = arrayInsertion [i-1]
        i = i - 1
print (arrayInsertion)
```

When running this code I get the following error message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Users\Ben\Desktop\insertion sort.py", line 8, in 
>   while  i > 0 and arrayInsertion [i+1] > arrayInsertion [i]:
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Are you using `i+1` when you mean to be using `i-1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is `arrayInsertion[i + 1]` when `i = 7` then `i` is out of bounds, since there's only `7` elements in the list. You're also not remembering the current value and index.

```
for i in range(1, len(arrayInsertion)):
    curr = arrayInsertion[i]
    pos = i
    while pos > 0 and arrayInsertion[pos - 1] > curr:
        arrayInsertion[pos] = arrayInsertion[pos - 1]
        pos -= 1
    arrayInsertion[pos] = curr
```

Which correctly yields:

> `[5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9]`

For future use consider packing it into a function `def insertion_sort(a)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def insert_sort(list_input):
    for unsorted_id in range(len(list_input)):
        element = list_input[unsorted_id]
        sorted_id = unsorted_id - 1
        while sorted_id >= 0 and element > list_input[sorted_id]:
            list_input[sorted_id + 1] = list_input[sorted_id]
            sorted_id -= 1
        list_input[sorted_id + 1] = element
    return list_input
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please review [answer]! Code only answers are less helpful than ones that explain how they work and why they are better than the code OP posted.

Answer (score 0):

you could also just use the built in .sort() method

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(1,7)
```

> Above line of code will produce 1 to 6 sequentially (1,2,3,4,5,6)

```
while  i > 0 and arrayInsertion [i+1] > arrayInsertion [i]
```

> arrayInsertion [i+1] in above line in try to access arrayInsertion[7] for i = 6 which is not present

So It will throw ***IndexError: list index out of range***